# What is the standard terminology for raster alignment?

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, coordinates, alignment, terminology

I would like to identify two types of raster alignment (assuming SRS is the same), but I am unsure of the correct terminology for these (or whether there is even a 'standard')?

First, there is 'pixel alignment'; i.e. pixels between 2 rasters are of the same resolution and share the same corner coordinate, but the rasters do not necessarily have the same extents.

Then, there is 'raster alignment' or origin alignment (or whatever), i.e. where two rasters share the same origin and extents.

Comment: I am not sure what the question is. Are you asking if your explanations are correct?

Comment: Im asking if there is an accepted terminology for these different types of alignment

Comment: I would say that if they share the same resolution, alignment, offset, scale and *coordinate system* then they are the same raster.

Comment: The common terminology for raster dimensions and alignment are: rows, columns, resolution, extent and origin. For two rasters to be "aligned", all of these conditions need to be met.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adjective meaning "of the same resolution and extent"](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/289431/adjective-meaning-of-the-same-resolution-and-extent)

Comment: @mdsummer What if they have different pixel values? Would you still consider them the same raster? I wouldn't, but maybe my concept of a raster is not general enough.

Answer (score 1):

I believe [Jeffrey Evan's comment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/152311/raster-alignment-terminology/294724#comment473414_152311) makes a good summary about the topic:

> The common terminology for raster dimensions and alignment are: rows, columns, resolution, extent and origin. For two rasters to be "aligned", all of these conditions need to be met.

Besides that, they would need to be in the same Coordinate Reference System (CRS).

---

Complementary, some terms come to mind when trying to make two rasters to align:

- **snapping**: when there is common resolution (cell size) and different cell’s coordinates.

  [image]

  <sub>Picture source: [Esri, ArcGIS for Desktop](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/environments/how-snap-raster-environment-works.htm).</sub>
- **resampling**: when there is common origin and different resolutions.

  [image]

  <sub>Picture source: [GISGeography.com](https://gisgeography.com/raster-resampling/).</sub>
- **projecting** (or reprojecting): when there are different coordinate systems. Other common terms are: to 'convert' or 'transform' between coordinates and coordinate systems.