# Adjective meaning "of the same resolution and extent"

Tags: raster, terminology

Is there a word that can be used to describe two or more raster grids having the same resolution and extent? I'm fishing around with words like "coincident" and "coextensive," but nothing feels quite right. And I'd rather find something more compact than "rasters of the same extent and resolution".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about [congruent](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/congruent) ?

co-referential

co-rectified

even [concordant](https://www.google.ca/search?q=concordant&oq=concordant&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l2.10666j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)   -- see the geological and medical uses.  A lot of technical terms are appropriations based on the original Latin or Greek roots,  eg: [cursor](https://www.etymonline.com/word/cursor)  (related to courier, etc).

Comment: or how about conformant?

Comment: Nice suggestions. It looks like "congruent" is used in this sense in *Applied Spatial Data Analysis With R* [link](https://books.google.com/books?id=v0eIU9ObJXgC&pg=PA130&lpg=PA130&dq=%22congruent+rasters%22&source=bl&ots=yDIE_qwSUj&sig=VJP6RtyEPO-BPJRiFcU3mnKX_c8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi5m6uPp6ncAhVr0oMKHWfSAOoQ6AEILDAA#v=onepage&q=%22congruent%20rasters%22&f=false). And definition 3 -- "coinciding at all points when superimposed" -- seems apt as well.

Comment: or more poetically: harmonious (free from disagreement or dissent?)

Answer (score 6):

The reason you are struggling to find a better word or shorter phrase for it is probably because one doesn't exist! I think "rasters of the same extent and resolution" is pretty short, clear, and unambiguous to most people who deal with raster data. Other suggestions, like "coincident" or "co-registered" don't (to me) imply the perfect match of one raster's cells with the other.

How about we use "SEAR" (Same Extent And Resolution) as an abbreviation? Sample usage:

> The DEM and the NDVI are SEAR rasters so we can add them in the raster calculator.

It probably won't catch on...

Two rasters could be same extent and resolution but different coordinate reference systems and so *not* line up perfectly. If you want to specify all those things equal then those would be SECAR (Same Extent, CRS, And Resolution). Maybe.

Answer (score 1):

Co-registered ?

To me, it means that the grids are compatible in terms of the spatial reference system and grids (but not necessarily the same extent as you asked).